# Hibernate 5.4.0 missing Tokenized option

Tags: hibernate

org.hibernate.search.annotations does not have Tokenized option in hibernate 5.4.0. I only see yes/no option in org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index. I am upgrading hibernate from hibernate 3.4.2 and want to know what would help me achieve the goal for the code shown below:

```
@Field(index=Index.TOKENIZED, store=Store.NO)
```

Comment: From what version are you upgrading hibernate?

Comment: hibernate 3.4.2